# Templating JSON

Tags: theming

Is there a way to template the results of a AJAX query that returns JSON data? The JSON is returned to a module.

Comment: Nothing built in, no

Comment: Well, just because it isn't built doesn't mean that someone hasn't tackled this issue w/ either a custom module or release a contrib module :)

Comment: You can create client side theme functions. Look at the examples here: http://engineeredweb.com/blog/11/5/javascript-theme-functions-drupal/

Comment: I've used handlebars.js personally

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) and use a custom .tpl file to theme the results of an ajax output by sending the variables to the template(tpl) file using the [theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme/7) function.